# Button position changing accordingly - customize for iPhone 5

Tags: ios, xcode, uibutton, iphone-5

I am working on my app to customize for iphone 5. I have button and want it to customize accordingly.

I have placed my button by drag and drop and placed where it should be. Now I would like to change the place accordingly.

It is possible? If yes, please let me know how. Since I am trying the change the position of my button in the following but it does not work
 in header file

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UIButton *opponentUsernameButton;
```

in implementation file:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

    screenSizeHeight=[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height;


if(screenSizeHeight==568)

    mybuttonOutlet.frame= CGRect(40, 80,125,150);


if(screenSizeHeight==480)

    mybuttonOutlet.frame= CGRect(40, 80,85,150);

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't need any code just set the springs and struts correctly, attach the button to the bottom of the screen and not the top.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use this :

```
#define IS_IPHONE ( [[[UIDevice currentDevice] model] isEqualToString:@"iPhone"])
#define IS_HEIGHT_GTE_568 [[UIScreen mainScreen ] bounds].size.height >= 568.0f
#define IS_IPHONE_5 ( IS_IPHONE && IS_HEIGHT_GTE_568 )

if(IS_IPHONE_5)
{
mybuttonOutlet.frame= your_frame;

}
else
{
mybuttonOutlet.frame= your_frame;

}
```

Hope it helps you.

Comment: I tried already but my problem is I did not create my button programatically. I drag and drop on myviewcontroller and it is not changing the original position.

Comment: Check have you connected outlet ? if not then connect it.

Comment: yes, absolutely. It is connected and shown on the screen but it is not changing the position.

Comment: When are you changing frame ?

Answer (score 0):

Solution is to Remove "Use Autolayout" from the button in IB or storyboard.